# Contractible orbit space of action of compact Lie group on Euclidean space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, transformation-groups

R. Oliver proved that the following in https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970955

**Theorem:** Any action of a compact Lie group on a Euclidean space has contractible orbit space.

My question is that this theorem is true for finite dimensional compact group actions on Euclidean space?

If $G$ is a finite dimensional compact group, then there is a totally disconnected normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is a compact Lie group.

So the question is reduced to

**Question** Any action of a compact totally disconnected group on a Euclidean space has contractible orbit space?

Comment: This seems to be related to the Hilbert-Smith conjecture. This predicts that every compact group action on a connected topological manifold factors through a Lie quotient group. It holds when the manifold is a differentiable and the action is by diffeomorphisms, and also when the topological manifold has dimension $\le 3$. In general it reduces to the cases $G=\mathbf{Z}_p$ for primes $p$. But in this case I'm not even sure one knows the orbit space to be simply connected.

Comment: There was some partial progress on Hilbert-Smith conjecture (by Williams, Yang, Floyd, and later, Dranishnikov); the problem whether hypothetical orbit space is a weak ANR (Cech cohomological dimension coincides with Steenrod cohomological dimension) is still open, as far as I remember.